# Navigation drawer theme resets on click

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design

As in title - it looks correct until i click a button. It's happening only if i implement a listener. Here's the code:

Kotlin

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.list_BT -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer1, MenuFragment())
                    commit()
                }
                item.isChecked = true
            }
            R.id.info_BT -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                    replace(R.id.fragmentContainer1, AboutFragment())
                    commit()
                }
                item.isChecked = true
            }
            R.id.preferences_BT -> {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, OptionsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        true
    }
```

XML - Activity

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JaBotMobile.Drawer"/>
```

XML - theme (kinda simple 4 now)

```
<style name="Theme.Base.JaBotMobile.Drawer">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_sans_regular</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.JaBotMobile.Drawer" parent="Theme.Base.JaBotMobile.Drawer" />
```

Comment: I've faced a similar issue where custom font shows weird behaviour when interacting with material components. I am not sure if all of these are related but does this GH issue describe your problem? https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/965

Comment: @ashu Yeah! It happens only to the font. You didn'd find a solution, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution thanks to @johnnyzen on GitHub. Thanks @ashu for pointing me to the source of the problem.

> Make sure NavigationView DOES NOT use:
> android:theme="@style/MyCustomNavStyle"
>
> but use:
>
> app:itemTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomNavStyle"
>
> @font/montserrat_regular